# Kann ein Angebot aktiv sein?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ich überarbeite gerade meinen Lebenslauf und habe dort einen Eintrag, der so aussieht:

> Eigenes Dienstleistungsangebot im Bereich Programmierung.

Ich biete dieses Dienstleistungsangebot allerdings mittlerweile nicht mehr an und möchte das vermerken. Ich hatte überlegt das so zu schreiben:

> Eigenes (nicht mehr aktives) Dienstleistungsangebot im Bereich Programmierung.

Nach mehrmaligem Nachlesen kommt mir das '*aktives*' aber irgendwie falsch vor. Kann ein Angebot wirklich *aktiv* sein?

Comment: Wie kommst du auf Grammatik? Mit Grammatik hat die Frage nichts zu tun …

Comment: Man kann etwas "aktiv anbieten" oder es halt "auf Anfrage machen". Ansonsten ist das Angebot halt da oder nicht. Wenn es "da ist", kann es zur Not auch "aktiv" sein. Schönes Deutsch ist aber anders. Falsch? Nicht sehr ;)

Comment: Eine Möglichkeit wäre, den Zeitraum zu nennen, etwa "Eigenes Dienstleistungsangebot im Bereich Programmierung (2010 bis 2014)". Dann hätte ein Leser gleich einen Eindruck, ob Du Dich mal ein paar Wochen in dem Gebiet versucht hast, oder ob Du ein Geschäft über mehrere Jahre zumindest halbwegs erfolgreich betrieben hast.

Comment: Dienstleistungsangebot? Das machen Firmen und Institutionen, das ist ein Katalog an festen Dienstleistungen, klingt sehr merkwürdig. Ansonsten ist der Vorschlag mit der Zeit super. Ich würde überhaupt nur einen Lebenslauf tabellarisch mit Zeit machen. JM2C ;-)

Comment: Normale Angebote laufen ab, bestehen nicht mehr oder sind nicht mehr gültig/bindend.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde das so nicht formulieren, sondern ich würde sagen:

> Eigenes (nicht mehr **verfügbares**) Dienstleistungsangebot

oder

> Eigene (nicht mehr angebotene) Dienstleistung

Es wird, beispielsweise bei Ebay, in WebShops oder bei Amazon, gerne von "aktiven Angeboten" gesprochen. Hierbei geht es dann meist um zeitlich begrenzte Rabatt-Aktionen im Sinne einer aktivierten oder deaktivierten Option (der Verkäufer muss ein Häkchen setzen, um das Angebot zu aktivieren oder zu deaktivieren).

Wirklich *falsch* ist die von Dir vorgeschlagene Verwendung aus meiner Sicht nicht, aber auch kein wirklich "guter" Ausdruck. Keinesfalls würde ich diesen aber in einem Lebenslauf verwenden.

Comment: Der Fall von Webshops ist meines Erachtens ein anderer, wo *aktiv* in der Tat ein recht guter Ausdruck ist. Es handelt sich dort immerhin um ein "Angebot" im Sinn einer in der Web-Oberfläche wählbaren Option, die tatsächlich nicht mehr aktiv sein kann, nachdem das zugrundeliegende Angebot ausgelaufen ist. Dieser Kontext ist jedoch bei einem Angebot, welches offenkundig von einer Person erbracht wird, nicht gegeben.

Comment: Ja, das sage ich ja. Ich hätte wohl einen Absatz einfügen sollen. Ich bearbeite meine Antwort nochmal.